# Change multiple polygons' area from square degrees to square meter in attribute table with QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, personal-geodatabase, units

I imported an ESRI personal geodatabase vector file (.mdb file) into QGIS, when I open the attribute table, it seems the the shape_area unit is in square degree.
I changed the project properties to a projection rather than WGS84.
But the units remain in square degree.
Is there a method that can convert all the data shape_area unit to square meters, then I can save it easily as csv file with square meters instead of square degree?
And should one be clever to choose the correct projection to a country to get the true areas or is there a universal projection?
The file contains administrative divisions.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute table fields are static. This means that your shape_area field won't automatically update when you change the projection, or if you edit a polygon and its actual area changes.

### Here's how to add a new area field in square meters:

1. **Choose an equal-area projection that uses meters as units.** Selecting the best projection depends on the size of the area of interest. [ESRI provides some helpful information on this topic.](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/choosing-a-map-projection.htm)
2. Save your vector layer as a new file with the projection you chose in step 1. QGIS can't create personal geodatabases, so you'll have to choose a different file type. Shapefile is a fairly safe choice if you're not sure.
3. Use the field calculator to add a new field for area in square meters. Use the expression `$area` to calculate area in the units of the layer's projection.

[image]

If you want a live-updating field, check the box next to "virtual field." A virtual field is only saved in the current QGIS project, so if you load the layer into a new project the virtual field won't be present. However, a regular field is good for most purposes.

**NOTE:** Different versions of QGIS handle unit selection for the $area calculation differently. As you can see in the screenshot here, in QGIS 2.18 the $area function uses the units set in project properties for the current project. Older versions of QGIS use the units of the layer's projection. It's a good idea to **verify the calculated area of at least one polygon by comparing it to the known area.** For example, if you have a country polygon, look up the area of that country on wikipedia.

Comment: Updating the existing field containing the degree area would work too.